The Limit of Power Law Toeplitz Matrices
Let $\mathbf A$ be an $N \times N$ symmetric Toeplitz with entries $A_{ij} = (1+|i-j|)^{-\chi}$ for an exponent $\chi$ above zero. Numerically, I can see that the minimum eigenvalue of $\mathbf A$ stays bounded away from zero in the large $N$ limit even for very small values of $\chi$.
I was hoping to be able to prove that at large $N$, $\mathbf A$ remains nonsingular by appeal to some version of the Szego limit theorems, but I have not had any success. In general, I have not found any accessible references that study the invertibility of such power-law Toeplitz matrices.
Is there a way to prove that this matrix remains nonsingular in the large $N$ limit at any value of $\chi$? Are there any references that discuss the invertibility of such power-law Toeplitz matrices?
